# TFS files last commit is different than current version in Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

this is really weird. I don't know how this is possible but if I do  ,,View history" on one of my files  the version I'm seeing in the last commit is different than what's in solution explorer. I think that both of those should be exactly the same and it seems that somehow I got the previous commit on my master branch... oO

Any ideas ?

Comment: they should be the same. Did you do a 'get latest'. What exactly do you mean when you say in "Solution Explorer"? How does the file look like in Source Control Explorer and on disk, when you navigate from Source Control Explorer to the file?

Comment: When you go to tab Code ->Explorer. On disk its the same as in Explorer (which is wrong because in the latest commit I commited an update). Well I wonder if this was some kind of glitch.

Answer (score 0):

You are right I am also having the same issue. 
After checking in depth I under stood that, it is the first check in datetime.

See below links
http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000436.html